# Length of string in sublist within a list python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of sublists of anagrams such as

```
L = [['terrible', 'elbirret'],
     ['supermonster', 'retsnomrepus'],
     ['you', 'uoy', 'oyu'],
     ['pears', 'reaps', 'spear', 'spera']]
```

How do I write a function that will  give me the sublist or anagram group that has the longest anagrams.

i.e. if the list were

```
L = [['spear', 'pears', 'reaps'], ['monster', 'sternom']]
```

it would give me

```
['monster', 'sternom']
```

Comment: By longest anagrams you mean the string length of anagrams?

Comment: So by "longest anagram" do you mean the anagram with the most letters or the anagram with the most possible combinations?

Comment: Yes I meant string length. Most letters. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a key function to get the list with longest strings:

```
>>> L = [['spear', 'pears', 'reaps'], ['monster', 'sternom']]
>>> max(L, key=lambda xs: len(xs[0]))
['monster', 'sternom']
```

**UPDATE**

> What if there were multiple sublists with longest of the same length?

Find the maximum length. Filter sublist based on the length:

```
>>> L = [['largest', 'artlegs'], ['spear', 'pears', 'reaps'], ['monster', 'sternom']]
>>> M = max(len(xs[0]) for xs in L)
>>> [xs for xs in L if len(xs[0]) == M]
[['largest', 'artlegs'], ['monster', 'sternom']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had one more question. What if there were multiple sublists with longest of the same length? How would I get it to print the multiple sublists out?

Comment: You can alwyas [flatten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) your list before processing its values.